# External storage doesn't show up in pc or disk manager

Tags: hard-drive, usb, storage, disk-management, diskpart

When I plug in my external HDD the LED on the disk lights up but i can't see it in my PC/DISKPART/DISK MANAGEMENT.

I tried all the ports on my computer but it doesn't show up.Help please.

HDD:- segate 1 tb go flex

Comment: Have you tried in linux too?
Does it show there?

Comment: yes i tried it on my laptop which has linux installed

Comment: I'm wondering if the USB-to-SATA bridge (that allows the USB to talk to the SATA disk inside) isn't being picked up. In Windows go to computer management console and see if you've got anything listed as "Unknown device" or whether the USB device is showing up as having a problem...

Comment: @BigChris sorry nothing like that shows up there

Answer (score 0):

If an external is not showing in Disc Management the options are:

Insufficient power going to the drive ,USB cable or port gone bad – you should try different USB ports, different USB cables and on a different machine. When changing the cable make sure the new one is as short as the original one, or even shorter. This is important it terms of providing enough power for the drive to function properly. It is possible that the HDD failed, in this case usually you should be able to see the USB interface listed in device manager. You can also download the manufacturer testing tool to test the drive. If the enclosure fails – most of the cases there will be no sign of this device in device manager, but it's possible that the drive will look like it's working – LED lid, HDD spinning.

I would start with running the manufacturer’s diagnostics tool